# Displays used in clocks - use with Arduino/ESP32/PIC

Tags: display

[image]

I'm working on a project with a micrcontroller and I need a low-power display similar to something shown above. Does anyone know what these particular displays are called and whether or not there exists ESP32/Arduino compatible versions of these?

I thought of e-paper, but refreshing every minute and those things are expensive.

Comment: It's not a graphical LCD, but makes you think that is not an LCD with large dedicated purpose segments?  There are typically ways to reverse engineer and drive them, but it's tricky, you'd probably want to be sure you could get several inexpensively before you started the project as you may damage a few trying to connect them.

Comment: VTC unclear since you show an LCD and then say that an LCD is not useful. Hard to tell what you actually want now and what you think these things are.

Comment: @pipe Apologies. I have amended it.

Comment: That is a really big display. Do you need it to be that big? LCDs are very low power, it is the backlight that consumes the power. Some are plainly visible in normal ambient light without a backlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom-made LCD.  They're cost effective if you're making 1000 of something expensive, or 10\$^6\$ of something cheap.

Us mere mortals need to find other solutions.

Comment: If you have time to spare: a bit on the order modalities of custom LCD panels https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvxgl-9tNM

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!